# Laravel | Удаление файла из папки uploads

Tags: php, laravel

Картинка которую необходимо удалить находится по адресу: "public/storage/uploads/item5.jpg"
Необходимо удалить её средствами ларавел. Я пробую так, и ничего не работает:

```
Storage::delete('uploads/item5.jpg');
```

В чём дело, как фиксить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что storage находится в папке storage, а не public.
используй

```
Storage::disk('public')->delete('uploads/item5.jpg')
```